# Eslint - Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, arrow-functions, airbnb-js-styleguide

I just started using Airbnb's eslint config - and it seems really good.

I am however getting the below error, and I'm unsure of what the fix is - I guess it's due to the function only existing to return a val.

I've played around with it - but I can't seem to make it 'correct'.

```
const getAccountInfo = ((e) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   ...
  });
});
```

---

```
[eslint] Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body (arrow-body-style)
```

Thanks

Ollie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having this error is, that airbnb's eslint config prefers implicit return with arrow function, you can fix it like this:

```
const getAccountInfo = e => new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...)
```

Comment: That's sorted it - thank you so much :) Not sure how I feel about it, but that's a whole other issue :)